# Converting an array of integers into an array of binary code in Python

Tags: python

I'm new in Python and need to convert an array of integers into one in binary code.

```
s_str = "test"    
s_acii = [ord(c) for c in s_str]
print(s_acii)
>> [116, 101, 115, 116]
```

What I need:

```
>> [1110100, 1100101, 1110011, 1110100]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Let me get this straight: You want decimal numbers that *look* like binary numbers? Are you sure you don't want the binary numbers as strings?

Comment: Try `list(map(bin,s_acii))` or `[x.lstrip('0b') for x in map(bin,s_acii)]`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't write code for you. Show us what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`bin` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin) to convert the integers into their binary representations:

```
>>> l = [116, 101, 115, 116]
>>> [bin(i) for i in l]
['0b1110100', '0b1100101', '0b1110011', '0b1110100']
```

If you do not want the `0b` prefix, use string formatting with [binary integer representation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
>>> l = [116, 101, 115, 116]
>>> ["{0:b}".format(i) for i in l]
['1110100', '1100101', '1110011', '1110100']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works fine! I tried the format function but used it wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `str.format` method with `b` as the presentation type:

```
print('[{}]'.format(', '.join(map('{:b}'.format, s_acii))))
```

This outputs:

```
[1110100, 1100101, 1110011, 1110100]
```